# JQuery .remove() is removing all label spans, how to fix?

Tags: jquery

I am writing a function that, when a value is added to a hidden input(the image id), which is the child of a visible label, a span that contains warning text disappears. Well, I got the warning text to disappear, but it disappears on all of my form elements. Thank you in advance for all of your help and input! Here's what I am dealing with:

HTML Before Change:

```
        <div class="form-group-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group ellipsis">
          <label class="media-library ellipsis">
            <label for="before-image-modal-trigger" class="generic-form__label"><a class="clear-image">Clear Image</a>Before Image</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="before_image" id="before-image" class="invisible" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/x-png,image/png,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" data-validation-invalid="Invalid filetype. The supported file types are: .jpg, and .png" data-validation-required="The media field is required.">
            <button class="button modal-trigger" data-modal="media-library-modal" id="before-image-modal-trigger"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Select</button>
            <span class="selected-image">Select a Before image file.</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ellipsis">
          <label class="media-library ellipsis">
            <label for="after-image-modal-trigger" class="generic-form__label">After Image</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="after_image" id="after-image" class="invisible" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/x-png,image/png,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" data-validation-invalid="Invalid filetype. The supported file types are: .jpg, and .png" data-validation-required="The media field is required.">
            <button class="button modal-trigger" data-modal="media-library-modal" id="after-image-modal-trigger"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Select</button>
            <span class="selected-image">Select an After image file.</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="generic-form__label">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="generic-form__input" data-validation-required="The title field is required." />
      </div>
```

HTML After Change:

```
        <div class="form-group-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group ellipsis">
          <label class="media-library ellipsis">
            <label for="before-image-modal-trigger" class="generic-form__label"> <span class="text text-danger error">The media field is required.</span> <a class="clear-image">Clear Image</a>Before Image</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="before_image" id="before-image" class="invisible" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/x-png,image/png,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" data-validation-invalid="Invalid filetype. The supported file types are: .jpg, and .png" data-validation-required="The media field is required.">
            <button class="button modal-trigger" data-modal="media-library-modal" id="before-image-modal-trigger"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Select</button>
            <span class="selected-image">Select a Before image file.</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ellipsis">
          <label class="media-library ellipsis">
            <label for="after-image-modal-trigger" class="generic-form__label"> <span class="text text-danger error">The media field is required.</span> After Image</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="after_image" id="after-image" class="invisible" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/x-png,image/png,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" data-validation-invalid="Invalid filetype. The supported file types are: .jpg, and .png" data-validation-required="The media field is required.">
            <button class="button modal-trigger" data-modal="media-library-modal" id="after-image-modal-trigger"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Select</button>
            <span class="selected-image">Select an After image file.</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="generic-form__label">Title </label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="generic-form__input" data-validation-required="The title field is required." />
      </div>
```

JQuery:
There's a .trigger('change') on the function that adds the image id to the value in the hidden input, btw. That's in another file.

```
if (field.is('input[type="hidden"][data-validation-required]') && $('label > span.error')) {
    $(this).on('change', function(){
      var value = $(this).val();

      if (value.length){
          $('label > span.error').remove();
      }
    });
  }
```

I also tried to see if doing if(value.length > 1) do the remove but that also removed the warning text from everything.

Comment: `$('label > span.error').remove()` this says 'remove ALL span.error that is the child of a label'. You want to remove span.error that is a child of the label in which this input was changed. Maybe `$(this).parent('label').find('span.error').remove()`.

Comment: That totally did it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. I've posted my comment as an actual answer for the benefit of any future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudo code `$('label > span.error').remove()` says 'find then remove *all* `span` having the class `error` that is the direct child of a `label`'.

You want to remove `span.error` that is a child of the `label` in which this `input` was changed:

```
$(this).parent('label').find('span.error').remove():
```